# Swift Package Manager - Distribute an already existing Cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I want to make my already existing Cocoapods available also as Swift Package.
Here's the thing. One of my pods depending on another, so I added this to my Swift package :

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Luminous",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "Luminous",
            targets: ["Luminous"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(
            url: "https://github.com/andrealufino/Deviice.git",
            from: "1.30.2"
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "Luminous",
            dependencies: [],
            path: "Sources"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "LuminousTests",
            dependencies: ["Luminous"]),
    ]
)
```

My other question is : why the Example folder is included when the package is installed? Here's the pic.

[image: Folder Structure]

Moreover, last thing, when I build my project in which I added the package, it fails because it cannot find the module for the dependency. The error is `No such module Deviice`.

I think I added enough details, if you need more, just ask.

Comment: Example folder is most likely included

Comment: In `dependencies: []` (in `target()`), you need to put that it depends on `Deviice` there I think. See Alamofire+Image (https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/blob/master/Package.swift) It tells where to find the Alamofire (base), and later, the Alamofire+Image needs it (in `target()`)

Comment: @aheze what do you mean? No way to exclude it?

Comment: @Larme great suggestion, with a couple of other fixes (on my Deviice library, the folder structure was not correct) it now works! Yours should be the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer about the `Deviice` not found. The other issues are about local paths.

You can see your package as such (In the next comment, "Package" can be understood as library, but also as an executable, for tests purpose often in the case of "sub packages", or "real executables".

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Luminous",  // Name of your package
    products: [],      // What packages people will see relying on internal sub-packages
    dependencies: [],  // External packages you relies on
    targets: []        // Internal "sub-packages", etc.
)
```

Each `target` has a `dependencies: []`, that's where you put the name of either other targets (which are "internal", or public one, that you stated before in `dependencies[]`.

```
.target(
        name: "Luminous",
        dependencies: [], //Put here names of either sub packages OR public package you "called before"
        path: "Sources")
```

In your case:

```
.target(
        name: "Luminous",
        dependencies: ["Deviice"],
        path: "Sources")
```

Indeed you wrote yourself:

```
.testTarget(
            name: "LuminousTests",
            dependencies: ["Luminous"])
```

So you stated that it depends on the sub package "Luminous", same logic here with `Deviice`.

You can use as an example the [Package of Alamofire+Image](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/blob/master/Package.swift). It uses as an external dependency `Alamofire`, and put it as such.

Comment: Perfect answer. I had to fix a path problem, but everything you wrote here is right. Thanks!